# Do objects need to remain in the room to provide their trend bonuses?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

Pretty much as the title says: Do objects need to remain placed in (one of) your rooms to provide their trend bonuses or are they permanent upon purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these boosts are permanent upon purchase. If these boosts required items to be in the room, they would eventually not fit in the room at all.

Comment: Thank goodness, my room was starting to look like a hoarder house.